# Why angular4 calls two times oauth/token?

Tags: angular, oauth, laravel-5.5, laravel-passport

I have problem but didn't see what make that problem. I made one laravel+passport project and try with other angular4 project to "talk" with laravel project. This is [start angular4 project](https://github.com/sandeeprajoria/laravel-passport-angular). But am stack. AS you can see in picture below [image: multiple oauth_token calls] when I click login it calls two times oauth/token to laravel project. Firstable time he have `Request method: Options`, and second one is OK and have `Request method: POST`. First one didn't return nothing and the other one return valid results with token and reset token. I don't see where is that first one triggered but second one is triggered after finished first request. Code where is placed click on login button is [here](https://github.com/sandeeprajoria/laravel-passport-angular/blob/master/src/components/login/login.ts).

Hope that someone can tell me what is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That first request options is part of CORS. This is normal. See this page if you want more details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS

Comment: It's Ok but angular return's me undefined in alert which is error part in this function https://github.com/sandeeprajoria/laravel-passport-angular/blob/master/src/components/login/login.ts#L30